# How can I find an expert CiviCRM WordPress developer?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hire a CiviCRM WordPress to perform various tasks in our Civi site. We have a list of needs, but the most pressing is the following. We have registration pages for our events. When you look at the registration pages on desktop, the form looks acceptable. But when you look at it on mobile, the form looks horrible and I can't image anyone filling out this form on mobile.

We need you to immediately step in and make whatever CSS or form tweaks are necessary to make the mobile view look good.

This is only one of several tasks that we need done. We are ultimately looking for continuous and long-term support.

Thank you,
Steven

Comment: I've [edited this question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/posts/16829/revisions) to rephrase it as a question which can be answered, per [this site's "How to ask" instructions](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This will hopefully make the responses useful to future people in the same situation as yourself. Thanks for asking, and being part of the CiviCRM community!

Answer (score 2):

A great place to find a CiviCRM expert is on CiviCRM.org! There's a list of CiviCRM providers at https://civicrm.org/providers

You can use the filters on that page to identify a good match by (for example) services offered, CMS expertise, language and location. Here's a listing of [CiviCRM / WordPress implementors](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country=All&service_languages_181=All&services=Implementation&supported_cms_s_182=WordPress).

Being an open source project, much of the work happens out in the open. Other places you can identify good people to work with are places like Stack Exchange (this site), [CiviCRM chat](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/), the [CiviCRM bug tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org), and other community resources.

Answer (score 0):

JMA Consulting would love to help you with this... we have a fair bit of experience with integrating CiviCRM and WordPress and are listed on the CiviCRM providers list. The premier WordPress shops in the Civi community, however, are likely Tadpole and Christian Wach ([https://github.com/christianwach)](https://github.com/christianwach).

Comment: Joe, just wanted to thank you very much for your input. I sincerely appreciate it!